# How can I view the current actions of a batch script?

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, command

I am using a batch script which moves a few files into some folders.

Currently it only says:

> 1 file(s) moved.

So if a file `a.txt` gets moved into folder `B`, I'd like to read that, not only that some file got moved.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for loop to print the and and contents of every file which is moved.

#### Code:

```
@echo off
set destdir=test
set /a count=0
for /f %%i in ('DIR /b %cd%\*.txt') do (
    echo Filename: %%i
    move %%i %destdir%>NUL  
    set /a count=count+1
)
echo.
echo Moved %count% files
```

Comment: Oh no, printing the content, that I do not want at all. The cli would go nuts. :P The question was overall geared towards a concise overview of which files got moved (successfully) after doing [this](http://superuser.com/questions/796613/how-can-i-move-files-into-a-folder-based-on-their-name/).

Comment: @henry: Ok, I modified it now.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Robocopy command to move the files it will show you a what was done exactly and its neat as well

Example of code to use:

```
Robocopy /E /MOVE C:\FolderA C:\FolderB a.txt
```